# Is there a way to receive push notifications translated from a foreign language?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, apns

I have multiple apps which I get notifications from but they are all in Hebrew. I was wondering if there is a way to let the notification go through a process in which something like Google Translate translates the push notifications and then I receive them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re able to tap on notification and select text in the app, you can use the app named [Workflow](https://itunes.apple.com/az/app/workflow/id915249334?mt=8). Just create a workflow for Actions Extension to translate the selected text and post it to Notes. Works for me.

Comment: This seems like it could work, but I am having trouble figuring out the steps to make it work. I downloaded the app.

Comment: Ok, here's what I've done: 1. Open Workflow and tap Create workflow, 2. Set type of workflow to Action Extension, 3. Swipe left and search for Translate Text option 3. Drag it to workflow edit mode window, 4. Swipe left again and search for Create Note & drag it to to Workflow. You're set now with it.                                                                                         * When Notifications comes up, tap on it and in the app select the text yo want to translate * tap Share and tap Run Workflow, choose the one you've just created.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible on the iPhone as a user.

However, the developer of the app can add automatic translation as a feature. This would require the messages to be translated in their backend before being sent as push notifications to your phone.